# How to update a LinkedIn scraper that should work?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, python-requests, linkedin-api

I am writing a python program

```
import requests 
import json
import pandas as pd

# Install necessary packages
# pip3 install requests
# pip3 install json 
# pip3 install pandas

# Get LinkedIn access token  
ACCESS_TOKEN = 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN'

# Search for computer science students  
url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/search?q=computer%20science&facetField=location&facet=us:84&facet=us:101&count=100"
headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}"
}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

# Parse JSON response
data = json.loads(response.text)
results = data.get("elements", [])

# Extract profile details    
cs_students = []    
for result in results:
    name = result.get("title", {}).get("text","")     
    contact = result.get("contactInfo", {}).get("emailAddress","")  
    cs_students.append({"name": name, "contact": contact})

# Create DataFrame    
df = pd.DataFrame(cs_students)

# Export to Excel
df.to_excel("cs_students.xlsx", index = False)
```

I would appreciate it if you could help me address this. I want to share free info with cool people on LinkedIn.

Expected:
An Excel sheet with names

Current Output:
An empty Excel Sheet

Thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried debugging? It seems like there are a lot of places this could go wrong that would allow you to simplify the question. For example, are you getting data back from the request? If so, you don't need to include that part in your question. Your problem is making the datagram or saving the file. If you're not, well that's an easier question. Your question is about making a successful request. The current question is just dumping a non-working program and asking others to debug for you.

Comment: The basic difficulty is your code is not runnable for others without a token. We don't know if you are getting an empty sheet because `results` is empty, or something else. We can't know that without getting an access token (which people probably don't want to do). But **you** could figure that out and tell us by simply printing  `data` and `results` and seeing what's there. Instead, you added a bunch of meaningless filler text ("Thank you for your presence", etc) and you're doubling down and calling me names. Fine. Good luck.

Comment: `why don't you offer a suggestion like I do?` I'll add, for context to this comment, that you have 35 accepted answers on stack overflow. Of those, 33 are answers to *your own questions* that you have accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there isn't a search endpoint in the LinkedIn API anymore.

The closest they got is Profile API where you can search for members by name, headline, or position. Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-vanity-name-api?context=linkedin%2Fcompliance%2Fcontext&view=li-lms-unversioned&preserve-view=true)

But this endpoint is restricted and requires that you get approved by LinkedIn.
I don't know how hard that is.

There is a scraper API from serpapi [here](https://serpapi.com/linkedin-search), but it is currently disabled. But you can sign up for their waiting list so they'll contact you when/if they find a workaround.